# Error segmentation fault al compilar un programa en C

Tags: c

Tengo un problema al compilar, cuando corro el programa me aparece segmentation fault, según tengo entendido esto pasa porque quiero acceder a una parte de memoria a la cual no tengo acceso, no se si es por los arreglos que estoy declarando.

Mi programa es crea un arreglo dinámico de 5 dimensiones, donde tengo que darle números del 0 al 100 y liberar la memoria

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Libera");
    int *****ArregloDinamico;
    
    ArregloDinamico = calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    *ArregloDinamico = calloc(5 ,sizeof( int ) );
    **ArregloDinamico = calloc(4 ,sizeof( int ) );
    ***ArregloDinamico = calloc(3,sizeof( int ) );
    ****ArregloDinamico = calloc(4,sizeof( int ) );
    
    printf("Inicio");
    
    for(int dim1=0; dim1<3;dim1++){
        for(int dim2=0; dim2<4;dim2++){
            for(int dim3=0; dim3<3;dim3++){
                for(int dim4=0; dim4<2;dim4++){
                    for(int dim5=0; dim5<3;dim5++){
                        ArregloDinamico[dim1][dim2][dim3][dim4][dim5] = rand () % (1000-0+1) + 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("Libera");
    for(int dim1=0; dim1<3;dim1++){
        for(int dim2=0; dim2<4;dim2++){
            for(int dim3=0; dim3<3;dim3++){
                for(int dim4=0; dim4<2;dim4++){
                        free(ArregloDinamico[dim1][dim2][dim3][dim4]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("Fin");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No estas reservando la memoria adecuada para el trabajo. Se puede ver que tu for recorre 72 posiciones pero solo reservas espacio para 20 ints.... eso no va a funcionar.

Answer (score 4):

Declaras un puntero quíntupe:

```
int *****ArregloDinamico;
```

El cual va a tener 4 ¿enteros?  en el primer nivel:

```
ArregloDinamico = calloc(4, sizeof(int));
```

Ya empezamos a ver cosas raras. Para empezar la reserva no debería ser `sizeof(int)` sino `sizeof(int****)` aunque también podría simplemente dejarse como `sizeof(int*)`. Lo importante aquí es el asterisco y es que en los equipos modernos (64 bits), el tipo `int` ocupa 32 bits, mientras que cualquier puntero ocupará 64 bits... es decir, con la línea anterior estarías reservando espacio para 2 elementos, no para 4 (128 bits en vez de 256).

Bueno, pasamos a la siguiente línea donde sigue habiendo problemas:

```
*ArregloDinamico = calloc(5 ,sizeof( int ) );
```

Aparte de que aquí tenemos el mismo problema con el tamaño de la reserva, encontramos un error nuevo. `*ArregloDinamico` es equivalente a `ArregloDinamico[0]`, es decir, si `ArregloDinamico` tenía 4 elementos en el primer nivel, tu solo inicializas uno de esos elementos ... el resto de punteros se quedan apuntando a posiciones de memoria aleatorias.

En las sucesivas reservas te pasa exactamente lo mismo, así que no me voy a repetir.

La solución pasa por reservar la cantidad de memoria adecuada a cada caso y hacer todas las reservas necesarias:

```
ArregloDinamico = malloc(4 * sizeof( int* ) );
for( int a=0; i<4; i++ )
{
    ArregloDinamico[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof( int* ) );
    for( int b=0; b<5; b++ )
    {
        ArregloDinamico[a][b] = malloc(4  * sizeof( int* ) );
        for( int c=0; c<4; c++ )
        {
            ArregloDinamico[a][b][c] = malloc(3 * sizeof( int* ) );
            for( int d=0; d<3; d++ )
                ArregloDinamico[a][b][c][d] = calloc(4, sizeof(int) );
                //                                             ~~~ Esta última reserva ya si es de tipo `int`
        }
    }
}
```

Nota que he reemplazado todos los `calloc` menos el último. `calloc` aparte de reservar la memoria inicializa todas las posiciones a 0. Esto no es necesario cuando lo siguiente que vas a hacer es machacar ese 0 por una dirección de memoria devuelta por `malloc`, aunque tampoco es que vaya a pasar nada si decides dejar los `calloc`

Como nota final, fíjate que hemos hecho un montón de reservas de memoria (se ha llamado a `malloc` o `calloc` unas 960 veces ... para dejarlo todo como estaba, debes hacer el mismo número de llamadas a `free`. Sin embargo tu únicamente estás intentando liberar el último nivel de las reservas:

```
for(int dim1=0; dim1<3;dim1++){
    for(int dim2=0; dim2<4;dim2++){
        for(int dim3=0; dim3<3;dim3++){
            for(int dim4=0; dim4<2;dim4++){
                    free(ArregloDinamico[dim1][dim2][dim3][dim4]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tienes que liberar **todos** los niveles que has creado con `malloc` o `calloc`:

```
for(int dim1=0; dim1<3;dim1++){
    for(int dim2=0; dim2<4;dim2++){
        for(int dim3=0; dim3<3;dim3++){
            for(int dim4=0; dim4<2;dim4++){
                free(ArregloDinamico[dim1][dim2][dim3][dim4]);
            }
            free(ArregloDinamico[dim1][dim2][dim3]);
        }
        free(ArregloDinamico[dim1][dim2]);
    }
    free(ArregloDinamico[dim1];
}
free(ArregloDinamico);
```

Comment: Cada dimensión no guarda un puntero, guarda un *n*-puntero siendo *n* el ordinal de esa dimensión. Así que `ArregloDinamico[i]` debe guardar `int****` porque es un puntero a una formación cuadradimensional mientras que `ArregloDinamico[a][b][c]` debe guardar `int*` porque es un puntero a una formación unidimensional.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no es C++, no estás usando `new` sino `malloc` y a `malloc` le importa únicamente el resultado de `sizeof` y casualmente `sizeof(int*)` es igual a `sizeof(int************)`, los punteros ocupan siempre lo mismo sin importar su profundidad ... de ahí que esa simplificación sea perfectamente legal y posible

Comment: Lo de que una dimensión guarde un único puntero no consigo localizar dónde lo he puesto o de dónde se puede llegar desprender esa afirmación

Comment: *Casualmente* `int*` es el mismo tamaño que `int****`, pero conceptualmente no son lo mismo. No está bien comer ramen con bolígrafos porque conceptualmente funcionen igual que unos palillos.

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar, *segmentation fault* es un error en tiempo de ejecución, no en tiempo de compilación; por lo tanto es imposible obtener dicho error **al compilar**. Por lo tanto, el título de la pregunta es incorrecto.

En segundo lugar, una formación<sup>1</sup> multidimensional, tiene tantos elementos como la multiplicación de todas sus dimensiones, por ejemplo, una formación de `3 × 3` tiene nueve elementos (`3 x 3 = 9`), una de `3 × 4 × 5` tiene sesenta (`3 × 4 = 12`, `12 × 5 =60`), etc...

Tu formación es de `4 × 5 × 4 × 3 × 4`, eso son novecientos sesenta elementos, pero tú has generado sólo veinte:

```
ArregloDinamico = calloc(4, sizeof(int));       // Cuatro enteros
*ArregloDinamico = calloc(5 ,sizeof( int ) );   // Cinco enteros
**ArregloDinamico = calloc(4 ,sizeof( int ) );  // Cuatro enteros
***ArregloDinamico = calloc(3,sizeof( int ) );  // Tres enteros
****ArregloDinamico = calloc(4,sizeof( int ) ); // Cuatro enteros
/*                                                 --------------
                                          total:   Veinte enteros. */
```

Además, has generado enteros en el lugar en que necesitabas generar punteros (más sobre esto, luego).

Para entender el error, voy a simplificar el ejemplo a una formación bidimensional de `3 × 3`, conceptualmente se vería así:

Empieza vacía:

```
int **f3x3 = NULL;

f3x3 ----> NULL
```

Creamos **las filas**:

```
f3x3 = (int **)calloc(3, sizeof(int *));

f3x3 ----> | 1ª fila | 2ª fila | 3ª fila |
```

Fíjate que las filas están aún vacías, así que creamos **las columnas**:

```
for (int indice = 0; indice != 3; ++indice)
{
   f3x3[indice] = (int *)calloc(3, sizeof(int));
}

f3x3 ----> |   1ª fila  |   2ª fila  |   3ª fila   |
                  |            |            |
                  v            v            v
           | 1ª columna | 1ª columna |  1ª columna |
           | 2ª columna | 2ª columna |  2ª columna |
           | 3ª columna | 3ª columna |  3ª columna |
```

Todo junto:

```
f3x3 = (int **)calloc(3, sizeof(int *)); // <<< #1 >>>
//      ^^^^^^                  ^^^^^
//         \                       \____ las filas, son punteros a entero.
//          \____ la formación es de dos dimensiones, por lo tanto: doble puntero.

for (int indice = 0; indice != 3; ++indice)
{
    f3x3[indice] = (int *)calloc(3, sizeof(int)); // <<< #2 >>>
//                  ^^^^^                  ^^^
//                     \                     \____ cada celda de la formación es un entero.
//                      \____ cada fila es de una dimensión, por lo tanto: puntero.
}
```

Dado que cada fila (en una formación `3 × 3`) es un puntero a tres enteros, necesitamos reservar espacio para tres punteros ¡no para tres enteros! (`#1`) un entero y un puntero no tienen por qué tener el mismo tamaño, así que si no reservas el tipo que toca podrás quedarte corto o pasarte con la memoria. Cada fila contiene tres enteros, necesitamos reservar espacio para tres entero ¡tres veces! ¡una vez por fila (`#2`)!

Respecto a tu formación de cinco dimensiones, los pasos serían:

```
ArregloDinamico = (int *****)calloc(4, sizeof(int ****)); // Primera dimensión

// Por cada dimensión, hay que añadir los elementos:
for (int x = 0; x != 4; ++x)
{
    ArregloDinamico[x] = (int ****)calloc(5, sizeof(int ***));

    // Por cada dimensión, hay que añadir los elementos:
    for (int y = 0; y != 5; ++y)
    {
        ArregloDinamico[x][y] = (int ***)calloc(4, sizeof(int **));

        // Por cada dimensión, hay que añadir los elementos:
        for (int z = 0; z != 4; ++z)
        {
            ArregloDinamico[x][y][z] = (int **)calloc(3, sizeof(int *));

            // Por cada dimensión, hay que añadir los elementos:
            for (int u = 0; u != 3; ++u)
            {
                ArregloDinamico[x][y][z][u] = (int *)calloc(4, sizeof(int));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

De la misma manera que debes reservar todos los elementos, también debes liberarlos ¡pero de dentro a fuera!:

```
// Las dimensiones son x, y, z, u y v
// Los tamaños son     4, 5, 4, 3 y 4
for (int x = 0; x != 4; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y != 5; ++y)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z != 4; ++z)
        {
            for (int u = 0; u != 3; ++u)
            {
                free(ArregloDinamico[x][y][z][u]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resumen.

- Reservas memoria para veinte elementos, pero necesitas memoria para novecientos sesenta.
- Reservas memoria para enteros, pero la mayoría de memoria que necesitas reservar es para punteros.
- La *segmentation fault* sucede porque accedes a memoria no reservada o a memoria reservada de tamaño incorrecto.

---

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 2):

Este es un complemento/demostración a las respuestas anteriores: muestra como definir y procesar en forma simple arreglos multidimensionales desiguales.

La idea es definir el `pentaArray` como un solo bloque de enteros y definir una función que calcule el desplazamiento dentro de él para un juego dado de indices.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define DIM1 3
#define DIM2 4
#define DIM3 3
#define DIM4 2
#define DIM5 3

int offset(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5) {
    // Calcula el desplazamiento para acceder al elemento Arreglo[i1][i2][i3][i4][i5]
    return ((((i1 * DIM2 + i2) * DIM3 + i3) * DIM4) + i4) * DIM5 + i5;
}

int main() {
    int num_elementos = DIM1 * DIM2 * DIM3 * DIM4 * DIM5;
    int *pentaArray = calloc(num_elementos, sizeof(int));
    
    printf("Numero de elementos totales: %d\n", num_elementos);
    
    //  Inicializamos el arreglo colocando en cada elemento el valor de
    //  su desplazamiento
    for (int i1=0; i1 < DIM1; i1++)
        for (int i2=0; i2 < DIM2; i2++)
            for (int i3=0; i3 < DIM3; i3++)
                for (int i4=0; i4 < DIM4; i4++)
                    for (int i5=0; i5 < DIM5; i5++) {
                        int desp = offset(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5);
                        printf("(%d, %d, %d, %d, %d) -> %d\n ", i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, desp);
                        pentaArray[desp] = desp;
                        }
    
    //  Imprimir los elementos secuencialmente.
    printf("\nElementos por desplazamiento\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elementos; i++) {
        printf("%i ", pentaArray[i]);
    }
    
    //  Imprimir los elementos por su indice
    printf("\n\nElementos por sus indices\n");
    for (int i1=0; i1 < DIM1; i1++)
        for (int i2=0; i2 < DIM2; i2++)
            for (int i3=0; i3 < DIM3; i3++)
                for (int i4=0; i4 < DIM4; i4++)
                    for (int i5=0; i5 < DIM5; i5++) {
                        int desp = offset(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5);
                        printf("pentaArray[%d][%d][%d][%d][%d] = %d\n ", i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, pentaArray[desp]);
                        }
    
    free(pentaArray);
    printf("\nFin\n");
}
```

produce (parte de los resultados):

```
Numero de elementos totales: 216
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0) -> 0
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1) -> 1
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 2) -> 2
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 0) -> 3
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 1) -> 4
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 2) -> 5
 (0, 0, 1, 0, 0) -> 6
 (0, 0, 1, 0, 1) -> 7
 (0, 0, 1, 0, 2) -> 8
 (0, 0, 1, 1, 0) -> 9
 (0, 0, 1, 1, 1) -> 10
 ...
(2, 3, 2, 1, 0) -> 213
 (2, 3, 2, 1, 1) -> 214
 (2, 3, 2, 1, 2) -> 215
 
Elementos por desplazamiento
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 

Elementos por sus indices
pentaArray[0][0][0][0][0] = 0
 pentaArray[0][0][0][0][1] = 1
 pentaArray[0][0][0][0][2] = 2
 pentaArray[0][0][0][1][0] = 3
 pentaArray[0][0][0][1][1] = 4
 pentaArray[0][0][0][1][2] = 5
 pentaArray[0][0][1][0][0] = 6
 pentaArray[0][0][1][0][1] = 7
 pentaArray[0][0][1][0][2] = 8
 pentaArray[0][0][1][1][0] = 9
 pentaArray[0][0][1][1][1] = 10
 ...
 pentaArray[2][3][2][0][2] = 212
 pentaArray[2][3][2][1][0] = 213
 pentaArray[2][3][2][1][1] = 214
 pentaArray[2][3][2][1][2] = 215
 
Fin
```